# Job DSL to create "Pipeline" type job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-job-dsl

I have installed `Pipeline Plugin` which used to be called as `Workflow Plugin` earlier.
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Plugin

I want to know how can i use Job Dsl to create and configure a job which is of type `Pipeline`

[image]

Answer (score 39):

You should use [`pipelineJob`](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/pipelineJob):

```
pipelineJob('job-name') {
  definition {
    cps {
      script('logic-here')
      sandbox()
    }
  }
}
```

You can define the logic by inlining it:

```
pipelineJob('job-name') {
  definition {
    cps {
      script('''
        pipeline {
            agent any
                stages {
                    stage('Stage 1') {
                        steps {
                            echo 'logic'
                        }
                    }
                    stage('Stage 2') {
                        steps {
                            echo 'logic'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
      '''.stripIndent())
      sandbox()     
    }
  }
}
```

or load it from a file located in workspace:

```
pipelineJob('job-name') {
  definition {
    cps {
      script(readFileFromWorkspace('file-seedjob-in-workspace.jenkinsfile'))
      sandbox()     
    }
  }
}
```

Example:

Seed-job file structure:

```
jobs
   \- productJob.groovy
logic
   \- productPipeline.jenkinsfile
```

then `productJob.groovy` content:

```
pipelineJob('product-job') {
  definition {
    cps {
      script(readFileFromWorkspace('logic/productPipeline.jenkinsfile'))
      sandbox()     
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: -1 Do not run `build` only stages inside a `node` declaration. This will allocate an entire executor for the pipeline which will just wait for the triggered builds to finish. At best it's wasteful, at worst it can cause deadlocks. You can just skip the node block and a flyweight executor will be allocated on the fly without consuming a full on executor.

Comment: @Diasiare Yes, you are right. I updated the answer. Thank you :)

Answer (score 36):

I believe this question is asking something how to use the Job DSL to create a pipeline job which references the Jenkinsfile for the project, and doesn't combine the job creation with the detailed step definitions as has been given in the answers to date.  This makes sense: the Jenkins job creation and metadata configuration (description, triggers, etc) could belong to Jenkins admins, but the dev team should have control over what the job actually does.

@meallhour, is the below what you're after?  (works as at Job DSL 1.64)

```
pipelineJob('DSL_Pipeline') {

  def repo = 'https://github.com/path/to/your/repo.git'

  triggers {
    scm('H/5 * * * *')
  }
  description("Pipeline for $repo")

  definition {
    cpsScm {
      scm {
        git {
          remote { url(repo) }
          branches('master', '**/feature*')
          scriptPath('misc/Jenkinsfile.v2')
          extensions { }  // required as otherwise it may try to tag the repo, which you may not want
        }

        // the single line below also works, but it
        // only covers the 'master' branch and may not give you
        // enough control.
        // git(repo, 'master', { node -> node / 'extensions' << '' } )
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Ref the Job DSL pipelineJob: https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/pipelineJob, and hack away at it on http://job-dsl.herokuapp.com/ to see the generated config.

---

This example worked for me. Here's another example based on what worked for me:

```
pipelineJob('Your App Pipeline') { 

  def repo = 'https://github.com/user/yourApp.git' 
  def sshRepo = 'git@git.company.com:user/yourApp.git' 

  description("Your App Pipeline") 
  keepDependencies(false) 

  properties{ 

    githubProjectUrl (repo) 
    rebuild { 
      autoRebuild(false) 
    } 
  } 

  definition { 

    cpsScm { 
      scm { 
        git { 
          remote { url(sshRepo) } 
          branches('master') 
          scriptPath('Jenkinsfile') 
          extensions { }  // required as otherwise it may try to tag the repo, which you may not want 
        } 
      } 
    } 
  }
```

If you build the pipeline first through the UI, you can use the config.xml file and the Jenkins documentation https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/pipelineJob to create your pipeline job.

Comment: Thanks! In my opinion this should be the correct answer. It was exactly what I was looking for anyway. I only want to use the Job DSL plugin to define the job itself, then have the actual code for the pipeline in the Jenkinsfile. I don't see what the point is in using the DSL plugin to define a pipeline.

Comment: What if I'm generating the code of the pipeline job but want to check it in to some repo and want the Pipeline job to read its Jenkinsfile from that repo? How can I do the check-in? Is that possible?

Answer (score 6):

In Job DSL, pipeline is still called workflow, see [workflowJob](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/workflowJob).

The next Job DSL release will contain some enhancements for pipelines, e.g. [JENKINS-32678](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-32678).

Answer (score 2):

First you need to install Job DSL plugin and then create a freestyle project in jenkins and select Process job DSLs from the dropdown in the build section.

Select *Use the provided DSL script* and provide following script.

```
pipelineJob('job-name') {
  definition {
    cps {
      script('''
        pipeline {
          agent any
          stages {
            stage('Stage name 1') {
              steps {
                // your logic here
              }
            }
            stage('Stage name 2') {
              steps {
                // your logic here
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ''')   
    }
  }
}
```

Or you can create your job by pointing the jenkinsfile located in remote git repository.

```
pipelineJob("job-name") {
  definition {
    cpsScm {
      scm {
        git {
          remote {
            url("<REPO_URL>")
            credentials("<CREDENTIAL_ID>")
          }
          branch('<BRANCH>')
        }
      }
      scriptPath("<JENKINS_FILE_PATH>")
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a git repo, add a file called Jenkinsfile at the root directory of your repo. This should contain your job dsl.