# Jenkins multibranch pipeline use Variable in Project Repository

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

Our Jenkins instance holds a lot of pipelines that their source is in a private git server, so all the paths are `${SERVER_URL}/group/repo.git`.

Today, we are using a hard-coded path all over the *Jenkins Pipeline Configurations* and *Jenkinsfile*, but in order to replace the server, we want to generalize this URL, to be able to replace it in one place.

We defined it as a *Global Variable* in *Jenkins Configuration*, and now we can use it in *Jenkinsfiles* by `${env.SERVER_URL}`, and in *Pipeline Configuration* by `${SERVER_URL}`:

[image]

---

### The Question

Now, I can't do that in the *Multibranch Pipeline*. Using similar configuration:

[image]

I'm getting the next error from the *Scan Multibranch Pipeline Log*:

```
Started
[Wed Feb 24 16:54:59 IST 2021] Starting branch indexing...
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 1.8.3.1'
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials tfsservices
 > git ls-remote ${SERVER_URL}/MyGroup/MyProject # timeout=10
ERROR: [Wed Feb 24 16:54:59 IST 2021] Could not update folder level actions from source f3de808c-bb6b-49f3-b4f3-08a1b4e749f5
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git ls-remote ${SERVER_URL}/MyGroup/MyProject" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: '${SERVER_URL}/MyGroup/MyProject' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2450)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2051)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1951)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1942)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.getRemoteReferences(CliGitAPIImpl.java:3381)
    at jenkins.plugins.git.AbstractGitSCMSource.retrieveActions(AbstractGitSCMSource.java:1148)
    at jenkins.scm.api.SCMSource.fetchActions(SCMSource.java:848)
    at jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProject.computeChildren(MultiBranchProject.java:598)
    at com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.ComputedFolder.updateChildren(ComputedFolder.java:278)
    at com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.FolderComputation.run(FolderComputation.java:165)
    at jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProject$BranchIndexing.run(MultiBranchProject.java:1032)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:427)
[Wed Feb 24 16:54:59 IST 2021] Finished branch indexing. Indexing took 22 ms
FATAL: Failed to recompute children of build-name
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git ls-remote ${SERVER_URL}/MyGroup/MyProject" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: '${SERVER_URL}/MyGroup/MyProject' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2450)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2051)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1951)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1942)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.getRemoteReferences(CliGitAPIImpl.java:3381)
    at jenkins.plugins.git.AbstractGitSCMSource.retrieveActions(AbstractGitSCMSource.java:1148)
    at jenkins.scm.api.SCMSource.fetchActions(SCMSource.java:848)
    at jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProject.computeChildren(MultiBranchProject.java:598)
    at com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.ComputedFolder.updateChildren(ComputedFolder.java:278)
    at com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.FolderComputation.run(FolderComputation.java:165)
    at jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProject$BranchIndexing.run(MultiBranchProject.java:1032)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:427)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example value for ${SERVER_URL}?

Comment: It is actually `http://tfs2018:8088/tfs/DefaultCollection`, Why does it matter?

Comment: Yea, it's not supported, many bugs regarding it have been opened over the years but they were all closed and the issue has never been solved.

Comment: try to use any job loader api, there you can easily achieve your scenario for both pipeline and multibranch pipeline . we are using [jenkins job builder](https://docs.openstack.org/infra/jenkins-job-builder/) extensively in our work and we loved it. This python library support a lot of scenario

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does not support. You can use `Single repository & branch`.

Comment: But this way I can use only a specific branch, right?
There is no "Behaviours: Discover branches" in the "Single repository & branch"